# implement ZKP in substrate

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, zero-knowlage

I'm building a custom blockchain using Substrate, and I want to include Zero Knowledge Proofs to enable secure and private transactions. Can someone provide an example of how to implement Zero Knowledge Proofs in Substrate using Rust?

Comment: in addition of the answers below, check out https://www.manta.network/ as they are doing a ZK parachain.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there are already pallets using ZKP.

I think it would be good to refer to urls below!

webpage:
https://brightinventions.pl/blog/zk-snarks-in-substrate-tutorial-supported-by-the-w3f-grants-program

github:
https://github.com/bright/zk-snarks-with-substrate/

Comment: Is it good pallet for production?

Answer (score 2):

There is something coming to Substrate!

We are currently adding the [Arkworks.rs](http://arkworks.rs/) elliptic curves to Substrate.

Check out: https://github.com/paritytech/ark-substrate, as well as the current PR which integrates the library into Substrate: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13031.

Also,this repos which provides example implementations and benchmarks: https://github.com/achimcc/substrate-arkworks-examples.